# Add a HTML text editor into website using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a html text editor to my website like the try it yourself examples w3schools has on their website. How can I get this into a html document? I don't really want it to be something you download, but using html, css, and javascript to make one. Can I do this or will I have to use a server side language like PHP?

Comment: You say "like w3schools", and ask if it can be done?

Comment: https://ckeditor.com/

Comment: You can look on Codepen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it can be done via HTML + CSS + JS. You will need to learn how to use [Document.execCommand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) to implement a Rich Text Editor in the browser.

You can [take a look at the example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Example) provided on MDN.

But many people prefer 3rd party editors such as *CKEditor*, *TinyMCE* etc.

Comment: Ck editor was more feature compared to tinymce editor go for ck editor

Answer (score 0):

If you want know how can it be done using scratch, its by making an editable div.
An editable div is nothing but a `div` with `contenteditable=true` attribute to it. Contents can be typed in or copy pasted with the same format. It will support html input too. You can track the changes done using `onInputChange` event.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `document.designMode = 'on';`
and learn about `execCommand`, here is a good [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_document_execcommand)